# Workarounds from Entity Framework 4 to 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm trying to learn Entity Framework with this tutorial [Getting Started with Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-4)

But I having trouble because the tutorial is using Entity Framework 4 while my visual studio automatically uses Entity Framework 6. I tried also to install [Entity Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8363). But the Entity Data Model Wizard don't let me choose if I will use Framework 6 or Framework 4

Here are the codes that won't work.

```
context.OfficeAssignments.AddObject(OfficeAssignment.CreateOfficeAssignment(instructorBeingUpdated, instructorOfficeTextBox.Text, null));

context.DeleteObject(officeAssignment);

var allCourses = context.GetCourses().ToList();
```

Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Karl\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Instructors.aspx.cs 44  55  ContosoUniversity

Error   2   'ContosoUniversity.OfficeAssignment' does not contain a definition for 'CreateOfficeAssignment' C:\Users\Karl\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Instructors.aspx.cs 44  82  ContosoUniversity

Error   3   'ContosoUniversity.SchoolEntities' does not contain a definition for 'DeleteObject' and no extension method 'DeleteObject' accepting a first argument of type 'ContosoUniversity.SchoolEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Karl\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\Instructors.aspx.cs 56  37  ContosoUniversity

What would be the possible workarounds?

Comment: #define "won't work". Compilation error? Runtime error? User error?

Comment: Fantastic. Could you also tell us what line? Perhaps the exact error message?

Answer (score 3):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1876088.aspx

Thanks for those links guys. Between the articles here and the links you provided I was able to read a bit more and figure out what was happening.

The root cause was the differences between EntityFramework 4 and 5.  This was actually noted at the very begining of the article, but until I had done more reading and then came back to it I had not understood what they where explaining.

(Explanation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/13/how-to-use-the-entitydatasource-control-with-entity-framework-code-first.aspx)

For anyone that finds themselves here looking at the same issue, the reason that the Contoso University example will not work in VisStudio2012 (or rather EF5) revolves around that fact that the database context created in EF4 was an ObjectContext, in EF5 yours is created as a the newer DBContext.  As a result the optimisation part mentioned in the tutorial will not work and you will get the error about not being able to cast to a ObjectContext (see the link above to fix this, you basically replace this part with an event call that creates your context).

The second issue I came across was in Part 4 where you update the GridView row via code (to Show the office assignments).  The reason is again the same, the old ObjectContext (when you looked in the SchoolModel.Entities.cs created) used an ObjectSet<> to represent table objects. The DBContext creates them as DBset<> and the methods in each type are different.

Instead of Addobject() us Add()
Instead of DeleteObject() use Remove()
Instead of CreateOfficeAssignment() use.... well, I wasnt sure so i just created an entity on the fly, I'm not sure if this is bad or not.
This is my altered code appears to work now (original lines commented out):

```
protected void InstructorsGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new SchoolContext())
        {
            var instructorBeingUpdated = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys[0]);
            var officeAssignment = (from o in context.OfficeAssignments
                                    where o.InstructorID == instructorBeingUpdated
                                    select o).FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(instructorOfficeTextBox.Text) == false)
                {
                    if (officeAssignment == null)
                    {
                        //context.OfficeAssignments.AddObject(OfficeAssignment.CreateOfficeAssignment(instructorBeingUpdated, instructorOfficeTextBox.Text, null));
                        context.OfficeAssignments.Add(new OfficeAssignment { InstructorID = instructorBeingUpdated, Location = instructorOfficeTextBox.Text, Timestamp = null });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        officeAssignment.Location = instructorOfficeTextBox.Text;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (officeAssignment != null)
                    {
                        //context.DeleteObject(officeAssignment);
                        context.OfficeAssignments.Remove(officeAssignment);
                    }
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                ErrorMessageLabel.Visible = true;
                ErrorMessageLabel.Text = "Update failed.";
                //Add code to log the error.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work (not tested..)

```
context.OfficeAssignments.Add(new OfficeAssignment(instructorBeingUpdated, instructorOfficeTextBox.Text, null));

context.officeAssignments.remove(officeAssignment);

var allCourses = context.Courses().ToList();
```